# How to remove time from date and time

Tags: c#-4.0

In DOB i am getting date and time  but i need only date

```
 foreach (DataRow row in ProfileDt.Rows)
            {

                UserProfileData.FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                UserProfileData.LastName = row["LastName"].ToString();
                UserProfileData.Email = row["Email"].ToString();
                UserProfileData.Address = row["HouseNo"].ToString();
                UserProfileData.City = row["CityName"].ToString();
                UserProfileData.date = row["DOB"].ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is giving you a string then you'll need to parse it to a date then back to a string with the desired date format.

```
string dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss" // REPLACE WITH THE CORRECT FORMAT
UserProfileData.date = DateTime.ParseExact(row["DOB"].ToString(), dateFormat , 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

If your database is giving you a datetime directly (which is the better solution) then it becomes even easier.

```
UserProfileData.date = ((DateTime)row["DOB"]).ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to DateTime type and use Date property, something like yourDate.Date
You can use DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact for parsing string to DateTime

It also make sense to return DateTime type directly from database so you do not need any conversions...